# Accessing variables in different methods in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've the below simple code, in which I have 2 variables defines in the `Main` method, and I need to access them from another method.

but I got the `variables are not defined`, though I defined them in the `declerations/main.d.ts` file as:

```
declare let voiceReady:any;
declare let x:any;
```

the `main.ts` file is;

```
/// <reference path="../declerations/main.d.ts" />
namespace CORE{
    export class Program {
      public static Main(): void {
            var voiceReady = new CORE.Listen(CORE.commands).commands;
            console.log(voiceReady);
            var x = 560;
            Program.execute('anything');
     }


        public static execute(spokenText:string):void{
            console.log('123');
            console.log(x);
            console.log(voiceReady);
       }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If I removed the deceleration from the `.d.ts` file, and added them to the `class` itself, I get compilation error as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare them as properties of the `Program` class.

```
namespace CORE{
export class Program {

    //Declare the properties here and access them in the methods
    static voiceReady: any;       

    public static Main(): void {
      this.voiceReady = new CORE.Listen(CORE.commands).commands;
      console.log(this.voiceReady);
      Program.execute('anything');
    }

    public static execute(spokenText:string):void{
        console.log(this.voiceReady);
     }
  }
}
```

If you want to reference from another class, import it outside your module like

```
import { Program } from "./Program";
```

and use it in your class like `Program.Main();`.

Comment: I got compilation error, I updated my question with this error, as I can not upload pic here, so I uploaded it in the question itself.

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks. what if I need to call it from another `Class`?

Comment: Added that as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel